# Swift: Firebase Analytics setScreenName

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

in my dashboard firebase analytics the screens are named by the name of their classes, I found a function:

```
Analytics.setScreenName("Pod tab", screenClass: "Pod tab")
```

I put it in the `viewDidAppear` but it still does not work, which I have to set something else?

Answer (score 0):

screenClass has to be "classForCoder.description()"

check this one. 
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/analytics/AnalyticsExampleSwift/ViewController.swift